# "FileAge" для файла по сетевому пути

Tags: delphi, база-данных, delphi-7, firebird

Есть хорошая функция «*FileAge*».
Вопрос:
Как ее заставить работать для файла с сетевым вариантом пути?
Потому что, при случае, например:

> «DateTimeToStr(FileDateToDateTime(FileAge('KOSTYA:D:\Eng.gdb')))»,

delphi выкидывает ошибку:

> > «…class EConvertError with message 'Invalid argument to date encode'…»

Такой вариант пути, программа берет из свойства «*DatabaseName*», компонента «*IBDataBase*».
Спасибо.

Comment: Чем же она хорошая, если объявлена как deprecated? Или в вашей версии Delphi это не так? Тогда уточните, какую версию используете.

Comment: я использую версию Delphi7

Comment: `KOSTYA:D:\Eng.gdb` это не валидный сетевой путь для стандартных функций работы с файлами.

Comment: Так и дело в том, что нужно именно на клиенте узнать последнее время редактирования БД? (при открытии приложения), т.е. путь который использует FireBird

Comment: Значит вам нужно этот путь каким-то образом преобразовать в валидный, который можно будет "скормить" функции `FileAge`.

Comment: Может, есть какой-то компонент в Delphi, который позволяет осуществлять вход на сервер с **учетом моей задачи**? И через который я могу вытащить свойства файла.

Comment: тут советуют, попробывать вытянуть из заголовка БД

Comment: Пока из этой ситуации вышел просто: Создал в БД, поле, типа "*DATE*", и буду в него заносить дату при каждом закрытии клиента.

Answer (score 1):

У вас путь к файлу неправильный. Все сетевые пути обозначены так:

```
\\<хост>\<шара>\<файл>
```

Косте надо прошарить папку с файлом, назвав шару  db например, тогда путь будет работать:
\kostya\db\Eng.gdb

Comment: "**Человек_Борща**" - не знаю как у вас **работает** такой вариант? Но у меня он с той же ошибкой "что и раньше" (**НЕ** работает)     ("showmessage(DateTimeToStr(FileDateToDateTime(FileAge('\kostya\db\ENG.GDB'))));")

Comment: @Konstantin78, извините, не заметил, редактор похерил UNC-путь. Обращение к сетевому ресурсу начинается не с одинарного, а с двойного слэша.

Comment: Да, действительно с двумя, работает. Но фишка в том, что **FireBird, работает с БД, по своему протоколу** (т.е. по закрытому сетевому пути, - когда директория не "расшарена"), а вункция "*FileAge*" - такого делать **не может**